# How do I use XPath to find the values of cells in a table

Tags: xpath

The structure of the Html I need to work with is shown in the screenshots below.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

I need to get the values of the first and third column of each data row in the table. There is nothing unique about the rows or cells.

I've tried:

```
 //String CPONEW="//table[@id='GridView1']/tbody/tr[2]['@id!= or @class=!"+j+"']/td[1]";
```

When I try to use this xpath I only get the first `tr[2]/td[1]` val but I need to get each `tr[2]` to `tr[12] / td[1]` and `td[3]` values

Comment: What did you try? Can you post your code as of now? And it is always better to enter the code itself than posting a screenshot of the code. Doesn't allow others to take the code into an editor and experiment.

Comment: i have used the Xpath for finding the tr rows in the above screen shoot  and teh xpath is List<WebElement> allExpandRows = c_WebDriver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id='GridView1']/tbody/tr[not(@id) or not(@class)]"));

Comment: i have got 12 rows that is correct. But i need to get the values tr[2]/td[1]&td[2] of each row

Comment: Use `findElement` relative to a webelement to get the values. Still did not understand what issue you have :(

Comment: i need the rows from tr[2] to tr[12] in that tr we have td also so i need that td[1] and td[3] values

Comment: //String CPONEW="//table[@id='GridView1']/tbody/tr[2]['@id!= or @class=!"+j+"']/td[1]"; when i try to use this xpath i always getting the first tr[2]/td[1] value.

Comment: but i need to each tr[2] to tr[12] / td[1] and tr[3] values

Comment: Assign the row to a web element, then use that web element to locate the individual cells (columns).  Assuming you have a web element called gridRow then to locate the text of the fifth data column, you could do `WebElement colFive = gridRow.FindElement("//td[5]");`

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```java
List <WebElement> tableRows = table.findElements(By.xpath("tr"));

List <WebElement> tableCells= table.findElements(By.xpath("tr/td"));

tableCells.get(1);

tableCells.get(3);

//you can assign to String 

String FirstColumn=tableCells.get(1);

System.out.println(FirstColumn);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out the first row based on its style, color property then match for 1st and 3rd column by using the xpath [position function](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-position). The corresponding XPath expression would be:

```xpath
//table[@id='GridView1']/tbody/tr[contains(@style,'color:#333333')]/td[position()=1 or position()=3]
```

With the following test input, you can test it [here](http://xpather.com/).

```html
<table id="GridView1">
  <tbody>
    <tr style="color:White"><td>header1</td><td>header2</td><td>header3</td><td>header4</td></tr>
    <tr style="color:#333333"><td>data1</td><td>data2</td><td>data3</td><td>data4</td></tr>
    <tr style="color:#333333"><td>data12</td><td>data22</td><td>data32</td><td>data42</td></tr>
    <tr style="color:#333333"><td>data13</td><td>data23</td><td>data33</td><td>data43</td></tr>
    <tr style="color:#333333"><td>data14</td><td>data24</td><td>data34</td><td>data44</td></tr>
    <tr style="color:#333333"><td>data15</td><td>data25</td><td>data35</td><td>data45</td></tr>
    <tr style="color:#333333"><td>data16</td><td>data26</td><td>data36</td><td>data46</td></tr>
    <tr style="color:#333333"><td>data17</td><td>data27</td><td>data37</td><td>data47</td></tr>
    <tr style="color:#333333"><td>data18</td><td>data28</td><td>data38</td><td>data48</td></tr>
    <tr style="color:#333333"><td>data19</td><td>data29</td><td>data39</td><td>data49</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The output should be according to the imgae below, only cells starting with `data1` and `data3` should match as those are the ones from column 1 and 3.

[image]